# How to programmatically center rotated text in TextView

Tags: c#, android, mobile, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 Community Version, I am trying to Center a rotated text in a Text View using C#.  (I mention Visual Studio version because some of the older questions do not help me as this version rejects it as Invalid syntax.)

This is the hierarchy:

(LinearLayout) tmrowInner ---parent of--->(LinearLayout) ll ---parent of---> (TextView) tv

Elsewhere in my code:

```
            tmrowInner.SetGravity(GravityFlags.End);
```

I have tried all many suggested values in place of "End" but to no avail.

And this is the code (inside a for loop changing variable dateindex):

```
 timetoenter = CurrentTimeSlot.ToString("hh:mm tt");

            LinearLayout ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(tmrowInnerId);
            LinearLayout llInner = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            llInner.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Pink);
            llInner.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            lp.Height = height +40;
            lp.Width = width;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llparms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            llInner.LayoutParameters = llparms;
            ll.AddView(llInner);


            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.Id = dateindex + 100;
            tv.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            tv.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
            tv.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
            tv.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 8);
            tv.LayoutParameters.Height = height;
            tv.LayoutParameters.Width = height;
            tv.Rotation = 270;
            tv.Text = timetoenter;

            llInner.AddView(tv);
            tv.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            CurrentTimeSlot = CurrentTimeSlot + TimeSlotAdder;
```

Pasting the image of what is shown - note time after 9:30 pm shows 0:00 pm hiding the 1 in the 10:00 pm.[image: What I see]

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Added target platform and device - Android and Mobile.